# How to Use Regular Expression in XPATH in XML in QTP

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xpath, qtp

I am facing a issue in QTP, i have to select a node value using regular expressions in XML

My Xml outputs the code as shown below

```
 <MessageElements xmlns="">
   <MessageStatus>FAIL</MessageStatus>
     <ErrorList>
       <ErrorCode>1951</ErrorCode>
       <ErrorMessage>No Data Found</ErrorMessage>
       <ErrorStatus>F</ErrorStatus>
       <ErrorText>OSSDataNotFoundError</ErrorText>
    </ErrorList>
    <MessageAddressing>
       <from>ICL</from>
       <to>ICL SOAPTester</to>
       <relatesTo/>
       <messageId>12345</messageId>
       <action>SearchResource</action>
       <timestamp>2008-09-29T07:19:45</timestamp>
       <transactionId>1234</transactionId>
       <ServiceName>SearchResource</ServiceName>
       <ServiceVersion>2.0</ServiceVersion>
     </MessageAddressing>
  </MessageElements>
```

Here if you observe the second line of the XML, we have `MessageStatus` but sometimes I get `messageStatus`.

I want to handle this situation with a single XPath so that if lowercase tag or uppercase tag `MessageStatus` appears it should match and return the value.

My code for Retrieving the value is as below

```
Set ObjXml = Createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

**Case 1**

```
Set ObjNode=ObjXml.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/.*essageStatus")
ResultText=ObjNode.text
```

**Case 2**

```
Set ObjNode=ObjXml.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/[m|M]essageStatus")
ResultText=ObjNode.text
```

**Case 3**

```
Set ObjNode=ObjXml.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements//wsageStatus")
ResultText=ObjNode.text
```

But none of them worked, please help me.

Comment: If you are testing the service that produces this XML, shouldn't this unpredictable capitalisation be considered a bug?

Comment: oLD REQUIREMENTS ARE WITH messageStatus

Comment: new requiremrnts are with MessageStatus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that always the first child element? You can try

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/*[1]
```

Comment: THIS IS RETRIEVING ALL THE VALUES IN MESSAGEADDRESSING TAGS :(

Comment: could you show your input XML? I could only take a guess when there is no input XML to play with.

Comment: /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/*[0]       This worked Joel. Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 1):

XPath doesn't support regular expressions in the way you're trying to use them (it doesn't support them at all in XPath 1.0), but you can do what you want with

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/*[self::MessageStatus | self::messageStatus]
```

assuming the namespace binding for the `soap` prefix is set up correctly (I'm not familiar with the particular technology you're using). If the namespaces cause a problem then the easiest workaround would be to use just

```
//MessageElements/*[self::MessageStatus | self::messageStatus]
```

to find `MessageElements` wherever it occurs.

Comment: Expected token ']' found ':'.

//MessageElements/*[self-->:<--:MessageStatus | self::messageStatus]

Line (7): "Set node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//MessageElements/*[self::MessageStatus | self::messageStatus]")".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot freinds for your inputs

Finally it has solved with the xpath /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/MessageElements/*[0]